# How Invoke Some method inside of none Control Class

Tags: c#, named-pipes, invoke

I use some Delegate and Events to Implement NamedPipes like this:

```
public delegate void MessageReceivedHandler(byte[] message, Client client);

public event MessageReceivedHandler MessageReceived;

void ListenForClients() {

//Do some

Thread readThread = new Thread(Read) { IsBackground = true };

}

void Read(object clientObj) {

//Do Some

if(MessageReceived != null)
MessageReceived(ms.ToArray(),client);

}
```

When I Use this event in Form Class(Inherited from Control object) the Implementation is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

public Form1(){
    pipeServer.MessageReceived += pipeServer_MessageReceived;
}

  void pipeServer_MessageReceived(byte[] message, PipeServer.Client client) {

      Invoke(new PipeServer.MessageReceivedHandler(Do_pipeServer_MessageReceived),
                    new object[] { message, client });
  }

  public void Do_pipeServer_MessageReceived(byte[] message, PipeServer.Client client) {
  // Do Some
  }
}
```

But when I want use this in some other classes that not inherited from control object I can't `Invoke` any methods and also I can't Replace implementation of target method `Do_pipeServer_MessageReceived` in Invoker method `pipeServer_MessageReceived` that rise an exception, so what is your suggestion?

Comment: Why do you need to Invoke it, what Thread are you calling it from?

Comment: @romkyns has answered the question. You only need to call Invoke in this instance if you are updating some part of the UI if not just just call the PipeServer.MessageReceivedHandler directly.

Comment: @Lloyd How can I call directly PipeServer.MessageReceivedHandler as you say.

Comment: Create an EventHandler in your other class(es) where required and assign that to the pipeServer.MessageReceived event. Make sure you Unsubscribe the same handlers if not needed.

Comment: @Lloyd I can't implement that, there are a lot of exception. can you give me a sample code?

Comment: Post the Exception raised, or part of the stack trace pertaining to the errors..

Comment: @Lloyd I almost sure that my implementation is not correct, I can't understand the MessageReceived fire in NamedPipe class, so how can I declare new event in other class? and how can I assign that to  MessageReceived?

Comment: Without know how you instantiated the WCF Service and What errors its throwing its near impossible to know.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities: you need to invoke the callback on the GUI thread, or you don't.

If you don't touch the GUI in that callback then don't bother with the invokes.

If you *do* touch the GUI, then you must by definition have a reference to *some* control you're updating. Call `Invoke` on that control. It really doesn't matter which control you call Invoke on; they'll all do the same thing.