# how handle an event that fired in threads

Tags: c#, events, delegates, invoke, named-pipes

I ask similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787550/how-invoke-some-method-inside-of-none-control-class) I use [this sample](http://wyday.com/blog/2010/multi-process-c-sharp-application-like-google-chrome-using-named-pipes/) to implement namedpipes in win form, but now I need to run that in console application so there is a problem in handle events, in original code some events declared and fired in some threads as following:

```
public class PipeServer {

  public delegate void MessageReceivedHandler(byte[] message)

  public event MessageReceivedHandler MessageReceived;


  void ListenForClients() {

    //Some code

    Thread readThread = new Thread(Read) { IsBackground = true  };

  }

  void Read(object clientObj) {

    //Some Code

    if(MessageReceived != null)
        MessageReceived(ms.ToArray());

  }

}
```

So in win form we use it like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

private PipeServer pipeServer = new PipeServer();

public Form1(){

pipeServer.MessageReceived += pipeServer_MessageReceived;

}

void pipeServer_MessageReceived(byte[] message) {

Invoke(new PipeServer.MessageReceivedHandler(Do_pipeServer_MessageReceived),
       new object[] { message });
}

public void Do_pipeServer_MessageReceived(byte[] message ) {

//Do Job

}
```

So when I use Console Application I can't use Invoke, Does any one know what is the implementation for this in console apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that for each event that fired in `PipeServer class` I remove that event and replace with the handler `(onevent)` so the above example will be like the following:

```
public class PipeServer {


void ListenForClients() {

//Some code

Thread readThread = new Thread(Read) { IsBackground = true  };

}

void Read(object clientObj) {

//Some Code

MessageReceived(ms.ToArray());

 }


void MessageReceived(byte[] message){

  //Do Job

}


}
```

And added a constructor for `PipeServer class` for needed implementation, at the end just declare an instance of PipeServer. This approach maybe not the standard implementation but worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at `SynchronizationContext` . Essentially you'll need some sort of main loop in your main thread, to handle those events.

Read more about it here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/SynchronizationContext.aspx

Comment: can you give me some sample link or code, the link you mentioned very ambiguous for me, please help, I really need it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke is used in Windows Forms to execute on the GUI thread. But since Console application does not have a GUI, Invoke is not provided. Does it really matter as to which thread executes the event handler ?

Comment: as I know that's not matter with which thread the event execute, and also I don't need any GUI to execute the event, so what is your suggestion?

Comment: Dont use Invoke in Console app.

Comment: So how can I execute the event that fired in some threads without Inkoke what is the implementation, can you give me a sample?